# FTP - Update many domains from one source

Tags: php, ftp

I need to updated many domains from one source.
The source can be a domain itself.

So say the source is www.source.com and I need to use FTP to updated:
www.one.com, www.two.com and www.three.com

I was hoping to get a push in the right direction on how to script this.
PHP is my preferred language.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Just use the built-in FTP client. Put the appropriate login information into an array, and any directory information in a matching array. Put a HTML button on the page, that when clicked, triggers a cross site synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.cyberkiko.com/page/FTPSync.aspx - It just copies the updated or new files.